# Number of sulutions for $c=x^2$ in an ordered field

Tags: ordered-fields

If $D$ is an ordered ﬁeld and $c = x^2$, where $c \in D$. How many solutions are possible? Please provide a proof or an example.

I know that there could be no solutions if, for example, $D \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $c = 7$, also it could have two solutions when $D = \mathbb{R}$ and $c = 7$.

Are there any other possibilities for the number of solutions?  Can there be exactly one, three or four solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Two hints:

First, suppose I tell you that $a$ is a solution to $x^2=c$. Then what do you know about the polynomials $x^2-c$ and $x-a$? What does this tell you about the possibility of having 3+ solutions?

Second, draw the graph of $y=x^2$ on the reals. Does this answer your question about the possibility of exactly one solution?

Comment: Okay, there could be one solution for y = x^2, when  = 0. And as I understand there are no possibilities to have more than two roots since x - a and x^2-c both = 0

Comment: Your second sentence makes no sense - how do you conclude that there are not more than two roots just because $x-a=x^2-c=0$?

Answer (score 0):

It's field.

Trivial case:  c = 0.  Then a = 0 is the only solution ($a \ne 0 => a^2 \ne 0.)

Non trivial case: c does not equal zero.

It's always possible that there is no solution.  That's a possibility.

Suppose there were one solution $a$ so $a^2 = c$.  Then $(-a)^2 = a^2 = c$ so c is also a solution.  If $a = 0$ then $-a = a$ so if there can't be only one solution.  If there is one, there are two.

Suppose  $b$ is a third solution such that $b^2 = c$.  Then $b^2 = a^2$ so $b^2 - a^2 =(b-a)(b+a) = 0$ so either b = a or b = -a.